# Have whole form retain focus when hidden div appears

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a form to take the focus, or scroll to focus, when a hidden div is shown on a select option event. I'm new to jQuery but have tried things like `$('#id').focus();` and also `scrollIntoView()` on this script --

```
$(function() {
    $('#continue').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $('#hidden').slideDown(2000)
            $('#hidden').show()  
            $('#continue').focus();         
        } else {
            $('#hidden').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

-- but I'm not sure if those are the functions I'm looking for.

If you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/snqL2pf9/10/, you'll see that if you select your favorite fruit there, I slide down a hidden div. However, the hidden div just scrolls down past the viewing window. I'd like the entire form to have full focus in the viewing window when the hidden div displays. So, essentially, as the rest of the form slides down, the viewing window scrolls down with it to bring everything into view instead of the hidden stuff just vanishing below the current viewpoint. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a callback function in the slideDown and then scroll the page when its done, like this:

```
$('#hidden').slideDown(2000, "linear", function(){
            var scrollDistance = $("#continue")[0].offsetTop;
            window.scrollTo(0,scrollDistance);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snqL2pf9/17/

edit: 
if you want the window.scroll to animate aswell, you can use this instead of window.scrollTo

```
window.scroll({
  top: scrollDistance, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful and is along the lines of what I'm thinking of. It does kind of snap though. What I'm looking more for, is for the rest of the form to slide into view below rather than for the top of the form to snap to the top after `.show`. It's along the lines of FAQ dropdowns where when you click the question, the answer slides down below whilst retaining focus.

Comment: check my edit. Or if you want it to scroll as it animates you could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/snqL2pf9/30/

Comment: Joachim, those edits are both excellent. Thanks. Both are very usable for my purpose here. Thanks for your time and interest.